# Matching a string with and without quotes with Regex

Tags: c#, regex, .net-4.0

Hey all, I know there are a lot of questions out there for matching quotes with Regex but the few I tried haven't gotten me far yet... I think its just a case of being new to Regex

Basically I'm parsing a unix grep command string and need to pull out all the grep'ed stuff.  An example:

```
cat theLogFile | grep "some stuff" | grep moreStuffWithRandomChars*&^^#&@_+ | grep "stuff" | grep thing2
```

and I would like the results to be:

```
"some stuff"
moreStuffWithRandomChars*&^^#&@_+
"stuff"
thing2
```

Thanks all!

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this pattern returns the results below as the first group

> string regexPattern = @"grep (.*?)( \||$)";

"some stuff"

moreStuffWithRandomChars*&^^#&@_+

"stuff"

thing2

Here is an example of how to use it:

```
try 
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"grep (.*?)( \||$)");
    Match grepStrings = regex.Match(commandline);
    while (grepStrings.Success) 
    {
        // matched text: grepStrings.Value
        // match start: grepStrings.Index
        // match length: grepStrings.Length
        grepStrings = grepStrings.NextMatch();
    } 
} 
catch (ArgumentException ex)
{
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the answer, but if you get a second would you mind explaining how that Regex statement reads for understandings sake? I would like to get to a point where I dont need to ask so many Regex questions haha. (Just the Regex pattern, Im confortable with Matches and whatnot)

Comment: @Hershizer33 here is a picture explaining the regex
[grep (.*?)( \||$)](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9439326/grepregex.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this addresses all your needs, but here's a pointer: you can split the string like this:

```
Regex.Split(string, "| grep ")
```

and then throw away the first part.

Comment: Perhaps I did something wrong but this: 

List<string> greps = new List<string>(Regex.Split(sender.ToString(), "|\\s+grep\\s+"));

Made greps contain each char of the input string, spaces and all

Comment: @Hershizer33 What do you mean by "each char" and by "spaces and all"? By the way, in C# 4.0 you can write just: `var greps = Regex.Split(sender.ToString(), @"|\s+grep\s+");`

Comment: Like if my input string was `"cat file | grep "stuff""`, the list contianed 23 items, item 1 being "c", 2 being "a", 3 being "t" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use regular expressions?  Why not just do this?

```
var cmdStr = @"cat theLogFile | grep ""some stuff"" | grep moreStuffWithRandomChars*&^^#&@_+ | grep ""stuff"" | grep thing2";
var results = cmdStr.Split('|')
                    .Select(s => s.Trim())
                    .Where(s => s.StartsWith("grep ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    .Select(s=> s.Substring(5))
                    .ToList();
// { "some stuff", moreStuffWithRandomChars*&^^#&@_+, "stuff", thing2 }
```